# jQuery get html of clicked link

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, html-lists

I need jquery to get me the html of the clicked link in the code below. Normally, I can get it. But this time the canvas tag is causing me problems. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<div height="250" width="250" style="float:relative; margin-bottom: 20px;margin-left: 20px" id="panel" name="panel" class="panel">

<canvas height="250" width="250" class="canvas" name=canvas" id="canvas">

<ul id="Comments" style="font-size: 50%;" class="Reg_Comments">

<li><a mthyear="August-2010" href="#" name="comments01">fast</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code and any debug information or error message in detail. Otherwise we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Close off the canvas tag or change your html.

Pretty sure that because you have poorly formatted html, this will be causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

yup .. canvas tag seems to be not to be closed.
Whereas the html on click should be a simple call -

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```